# Geoserver css Icon size/ scale best practise

Tags: geoserver-css-module

Currently  my rules for styling point Icons bound to scale look like this:

```
:mark{
  mark: url("file:./icon.svg");
  mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";
}

[atrib='xyz'][@scale > 600 ][@scale < 1000] {
  mark-size:10;
}

[atrib='xyz'][@scale > 400 ][@scale < 600]  {
  mark-size:60;
}

[atrib='xyz'][@scale < 400]  {
  mark-size:120;
}
```

It´s hard to guess the correct icon size compared to scale. (Trial and error).

Questions:

- is there a best practice like "between scale  600 and 1000 mark
  size X is appropriated" (or a formular?)
- which unit is "mark-size"?
  pt, px,em?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is essentially unanswerable by anyone but you who can see your mark and the type of map you are creating. Personally I usually go for small rather than big unless the whole point of the map is the markers.

For your second question the default unit of measure is pixels (px) but it could also be feet (ft) or metres (m) which would allow your mark to grow or shrink as the user zooms the map. See the [CSS documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/extensions/css/valuetypes.html) for details of how to set these and which size value determines the units of an object.

Comment: thanks again iant, one more related question. does openlayer getScale() tell the same scale calculation as min-maxScaleDenominator  used in SLDs ? I´m asking because checking console.log(map.getScale()); a SLD rule should grip but does not. To make a long story short: Can I log current OL scaleDenominator to see if I´m "inside" a SLD min-maxScaleDenominator? This would be useful for working on mark-size.

Comment: You need to set OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH to match your server - check the image preview of a GeoServer site to see an example

Comment: Uff, seems you know what I´m looking for hours now. But I´m a bit to inexperienced to follow your advise. with "check the preview …" do you mean to check an Openlayers layerpreview of geoserver, if so where do I get correct Dots_Per_inch from. Or do you mean the general examples? http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/zoomLevels.html   thanks a lot!

Comment: I meant one of the GeoServer layer previews - but you can just set it to the OGC standard output resolution of 90 DPI.

Comment: Ok so by creating the OL map setting OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH to 90 should work?

Comment: quick and dirty this seems to work as well console.log("scale: " +map.getScale()*1.2857142857); = map.getScale()*   90dpi / 70dpi  thanks!